# How to create .pkg file using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to create a pkg file using applescript.I have gone through various applescript tutorials and studied the  [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/as_related_apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001570-1148133-BAJJGIBG)
but I couldn't find the solution.Can any one guide me in accomplishing this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you mean you want to create a .pkg of an Applescript application, you can use PackageMaker, part of the Apple Developer Tools. If you want to use AppleScript to create packages automatically, most Apple apps are scriptable, and I wouldn't be surprised if PackageMaker is.

[Developer Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: You should post your solution as a separate answer.